# Whenever I am Executing my git commands by SSH-ing I am getting an error In c# code output

Tags: c#, ssh, cmd, command-prompt

My main objective is to Run some commands in cmd using C# code and get the final response as output.
This is my code:

```
                processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe",
                ""/c ssh kovair@192.168.12.232 \"cd git_home && git log --pretty=format:\"%H \" 
                --after=\"2021-05-20T11:08:00.000000Z\" 
                --until=\"2021-06-17T23:51:01.000000Z\"\"");
                processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\xyz\.ssh";
                // initialising process and executing it.
                process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.Start();
                //reading the output
                string response = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        
                string error = (string)(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

Here basically I am executing

> ssh   kovair@192.168.12.232 "cd git_home && git log
> --pretty=format:"%H " --after="2021-05-20T11:08:00.000000Z" --until="2021-06-17T23:51:01.000000Z""

in path

> C:\Users\xyz.ssh

Which should get me the Commit Ids from the git server. but here I am getting empty response and in error I am getting

> 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

If I manually execute the command it returns me the desired data but when executing it through C# code I am getting this error can anyone help to fix this error